# how to paste a file into another file (turn one), but one under the other?

Tags: terminal, paste

I want to paste one file (with vectos 1xn) in another file?
Example:

File1

```
rs01  rs02  rs03
```

File2

```
AA     BB    CC
```

How I can do this? But in my case, I have 55,000 column in File1 and File2, so, I've been thinking that is difficult to use the command  to put head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cat` utility con*cat*enates all its inputs into one data stream.

Giving it two files, it produces output consisting of the complete contents of the first file, followed by the complete contents of the second file, in that order.

In your case:

```
$ cat file1 file2 >file-1-and-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

Or you can try the following

```
while read LINE
do
           echo $LINE >> file2
 done < file1
```